# Overlapping query in Mysql php execution

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to find the answer but still didn't get the solution.

In a binary tree auto spillage system. Say that member "A" has two legs, left and right (both still empty). When a new member ("B") comes to make registration, the system checks if the left legs of A is still empty and of course it is, the system then 'remember' the left legs of "A" as an 'empty' slot and will give it to "B". "B" takes some minutes to complete the registration until it done. So far so good.

The problem comes from here :

During the completion of "B" registration. Other new member, "C", make a registration as well. The system checks if the left legs of A is still empty and of course it is ( because "B" not yet complete the query).

When registration of B has done, the left leg of A is fill by B. But when C has done, C overwrite the B.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe introduce a "reserved" state, and store "who" it's reserved by along with a timeout so it can't stay permenantly reserved if the first new member never complets their registration.

Comment: At the point when the system *remembers* that the empty left branch was *assigned* to `B` member, it has to also remember that this branch *temporarily* is not empty. Therefore when `C` comes to register, system checks empty branches and takes into count those *temporarily* assigned. Those temporarily assigned should be released (again consider empty) if `B` does not finish registration in given time.

Comment: Almost same answers above. I think that is the solution. Great Idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B` comes and marks `A` left leg as `Reserved by B`, `C` comes and see, that `A` has only right leg empty, so it takes it. `B` end registration and marks `A` left leg as `Taken`. If `B` cancels registration, `A` left leg becomes `empty`